# PHP error in `gettype`

Tags: php

I am PHP developer and I am trying to use following code but I don't know I am getting wrong error in PHP 7 but it's working fine at PHP 5:

```
$output = 5;
echo gettype($output);
```

The output is:

> integerarray

Comment: Your code outputs `integer`. Your `array` output seems to come from another code.

Comment: working fine. No any issue. Just tested

Comment: working file in php7 just tested https://eval.in/938784

Answer (score 1):

Your code returns:

> integer

for every version of PHP from 5.0.4 to 7.1.0.

You can test it online with this [PHP Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com).

Comment: Yes, But I don't know I am getting integerarray.  Actually I am giving an test on https://app.codility.com/demo/take-sample-test/   I write following code but its giving me output as array which should not be .


function solution($n,$A) {
    // write your code in PHP7.0
    
 if($n<0){
  $output = 1;
 }else{
  $output = $n;
 }

    if($output==in_array($output,$A)){
     $output++;
      solution($output,$A);
    }else{
     echo $output;
    }   
}

$A = array(1,3,6,4,1,2);

solution(min($A),$A);